# Authenticating API Request outside of Postman using Python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, postman, hmac

I am using an API for a portfolio management software and have been provided some documentation on how to implement it through Postman. The results come clean through Postman, but when I try to replicate the script through Python, I am unable to authenticate. I am not well versed in any other language besides Python and I am no API expert (especially when it comes to authentication). I was hoping that someone might be able to look through this code and see if anything seems incorrect with respect to creating a unique signature. Or, if anyone has had experience with creating an HMAC signature using the python requests structure.

```
import requests
import uuid
import time
import hmac
import base64
import hashlib
import math

url = "url"

payload = "{\n\t\"firm\": \"XXXXXXXX\",\n\t\"id\": \"#######\",\n\t\"data\": {\n\t\t\"tracking_preference\": 2\n\t} \n}\n"

apikey = 'apikey'

uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
ts = math.floor(time.time())
timestamp = str(ts)

signature = timestamp+uuid

#signature_bytes = signature.encode('UTF8')
#secret_bytes = base64.standard_b64decode(apikey)

signature_bytes = bytes(signature, 'UTF8')
secret_bytes = bytes(apikey, 'UTF8')

signature_hash = hmac.new(secret_bytes, signature_bytes, hashlib.sha256).digest()
hmac = base64.b64encode(signature_hash).decode()


headers = {
    'X-SL-UUID': uuid,
    'X-SL-Timestamp': timestamp,
    'X-SL-HMAC': hmac,
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.18.0",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "unique token",
    'Host': "xxxxxx-xxx.smartleaf.com",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Content-Length': "89",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Anything with "XXX" or "###" is information I have blurred out. Thanks in advance!

Here is the pre-request script on Postman using JS:

```
var apikey = '##########';

var uuidlib = require('uuid');
var uuid = uuidlib.v4();

var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).toString();

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(timestamp.concat(uuid), apikey);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable('timestamp', timestamp);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('uuid', uuid);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('hmac', hash);
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem comes from the HMAC signature ? Since you can do it on Postman and cannot on Python, can you tell what differs from Python and Postman ? What's the answer you're getting for the URL you're trying to hit ?

Comment: what error are you getting back?  can you include details of what their server is expecting, or at least a link to the docs?  I'd suggest removing most of those headers, e.g. `Content-Length` and `Connection` should almost certainly be under the control of `requests`

Comment: @IMCoins This is the response I am currently getting: ''' {"status":"error","errors":[{"code":2000,"title":"Unable to authenticate","message":"Unable to authenticate. Please contact Smartleaf."}],"data":{}} ''' So, it seems as the authentication is not working through my python script which leads me to think it comes from the HMAC signature. On the Postman side, I am getting a successful response.

Comment: They say to contact them, that's what you should do in my opinion. The code `2000` is not a conventional status code to me, did you mean `200`  or was it really `2000` ?

Comment: @Sam Mason I am unable to send the docs, but essentially they are requiring the "X-SL-UUID", "X-SL-Timestamp", and "X-SL-HMAC" headers. So a unique id concatenated with a timestamp and the api key to create an HMAC signature. The pre-request script on postman is written in JS and I will try to attach that

Comment: @IMCoins Error Code 2000 is a legitimate response code from the server I am trying to connect to -- unable to authenticate.

Comment: @Sam Mason I have edited my post and added the postman pre-request script

Comment: You must use a requests session, and do a `get()` before the `post()` because the server often delivers a cookie with the `get()` that will be automatically sent with the `post()` because it is stored by the session. Then ensure you know what the site expects (Headers, parameters, content)  by tracing the messages to/fro for a browser login using an app like Telerik Fiddler (Windows) or e.g. mitm (Linux). Then get your code to replicate those header/parameters/http requests. Then keep using the session because it keeps delivering the ‘this is an authenticated client’ cookie With every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

directly translating that Javascript code results in:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
import uuid
import requests

apikey = b'##########'
url = 'https://xxxxxx-xxx.smartleaf.com/'
payload = {'firm': 'XXXXXXXX', 'id': '#######', 'data': {'tracking_preference': 2}}

reqid = str(uuid.uuid4())
reqts = str(int(time.time()))

key = hmac.new(apikey, f'{reqts}{reqid}'.encode('ascii'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

headers = {
    'X-SL-UUID': reqid,
    'X-SL-Timestamp': reqts,
    'X-SL-HMAC': key,
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

the main this is you were encoding the digest in base64 rather than hexadecimal

obviously I can't test this, but hopefully it's about right

Comment: Yes, I removed the base64 encoding and utilized hexadecimal. I've created a successful connection now. Thanks for the help!